# Need A Remember Me in Community Builder Login Screen

Tags: lightning-experience, community-builder

How to add Remember Me Checkbox in Login Screen with using Community Builder
**Note:I am using Napili Template for build the application.**

Comment: I believe that's done through the OS, not by code in your login screen. It's the browser that remembers the login username and pw unless the user has a pw keeper utility.